# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

"В частности, по экспертным оценкам(,) сумма составит около 100 руб."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, здесь запятая не нужна. "По экспертным оценкам" не является ни простым предложением в составе сложного, ни вводным оборотом.

Comment: А как тогда быть с выражением "по статистике"? (По статистике, 9 человек из 10 любят мороженое.") В Грамоте.ру рекомендуют оборот "по статистике" обособлять - как источник информации.